# BLUENRG-LP BLE Antenna Design Query

Tags: impedance-matching, bluetooth-low-energy, passive-filter

I am developing a small Bluetooth Low Energy product using the BLUENRG-LP series of SoC from ST Microelectronics. For the RF matching part, I was told on their forum to just copy the design in their evaluation board or from page 7 of linked application note.

https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an5526-pcb-design-guidelines-for-the-bluenrglp-bluenrglps-devices-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Below is the screen shot of the recommended circuit.

[image: Recommended Matching Circuit]

I am curious as to how this circuit actually works. I am new to RF circuit design and would like some guidance on how to interpret this design, and also how to prepare myself to design circuits like this in future if the need be. Some useful study material would also be highly appreciated.

Comment: a literature search for **cascaded low-pass LC filter design** might help. These filters help attenuate harmonics to meet FCC requirements for spurious emissions. It is also possible to transform a source impedance to a different load impedance (not done here). Since the implementation will be with surface-mount components on a printed circuit board, you should also learn about PCB transmission lines as well.

Comment: Why don't you use a simulator?

Comment: @Andyaka Could you suggest a good free simulator please? I am just getting my feet wet with the RF stuff, so a simulator will come in pretty handy.

Comment: I use micro-cap; others use LTspice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter shown is somewhat odd, because it cascades a stage of an **elliptic low pass filter** with a stage of **Chebychev low pass filter**.
In learning their characteristics, one might analyze each stage separately, recognizing that their individual frequency responses are somewhat altered when you cascade them together.
In this case, source resistance (40 ohms) is nearly equal to load resistance (50 ohms), so you might start with a filter that has equal source & load. These filters can efficiently transform source resistance to a different load resistance, complicating component selection. Some web applets and design aids might help you to see how component values vary as design parameters change.
Design parameters might include:

- source resistance
- load resistance
- cut-off frequency (for a low-pass or high-pass filter)
- loaded Q
- ripple (for Chebychev filter)
- stop-band floor (for elliptic filter)

Some starting values in an applet for examining this filter might set these parameters in this ballpark:

- cut-off frequency near 3 GHz
- input/output resistance 50 ohms
- Chebychev ripple 0.01 dB

At this high frequency, component tolerance, its "ideal-ness" and its mounting environment can influence the value selected. A designer might attempt building a paper-design filter, and tweak selected values from measurements of the filter - this requires knowledge of which component(s) to tweak, and whether to increase/decrease values. In any case, an accountable designer would ensure that the filter attenuates spurs regulated by RF spectrum authorities.

If you prefer a more mathematical approach, the definitive tome on filter design is Anatol Zverev's "*Handbook of Filter Synthesis*". Since this was at the dawn of applying computer analysis to filters, you can see how modern computer designs apply the math.

---

For a more basic filter design, you might simply ask, "At 3 GHz., what inductor and capacitor values give an impedance of 50 ohms?"

- At 3 GHz, capacitor would be near 1pf. (near the OP's filter value of 0.8pf)
- At 3 GHz, inductor would be near 2.7 nH. (near the OP's filter value of 3.3nH)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. The handbook of filter synthesis looks very interesting.